# как сделать чтобы по нажатию мышкой на цифру она улетала в окошко домика?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

1. это код с основного файла
   при нажатии на F1 меняется картинка

   ```
   import pyttsx3
   from gtts import gTTS
   from setincs import*


   game_loop = False
   draw_pikcher()
   while  game_loop == False:
       for event in pg.event.get():
           keys = pg.key.get_pressed()
           if keys[pg.K_F1]:
               draw_dom()
               draw_nambers()
               draw_namberse()
               print(f'успешно')

           if keys[pg.K_F2]:
               draw_pikcher()

           if keys[pg.K_ESCAPE]:
               pg.quit()
               game_loop = True
               print(f'игра закрыта')
               break
   ```

2. часть с файла настроек

   ```
   import pygame
   pg = pygame

   WHITE = (255,255,255)

   pg.init()
   screen = pg.display.set_mode((13, 78), pg.FULLSCREEN)
   pg.display.set_caption('числовые домики ')

   def draw_pikcher():
       bd = pg.image.load('bd.png.png')
       bd = pg.transform.scale(bd, (350,350))
       phon = pg.image.load("foni.png")
       phon = pg.transform.scale(phon, (1350, 780))
       screen.blit(phon, (0,0))
       screen.blit(bd, (400, 410))
       pg.display.update()

   def draw_dom():
       screen.fill(WHITE)
       pg.display.update()
       fon = pg.image.load("dom.png")
       fon = pg.transform.scale(fon, (800,700))
       screen.blit(fon, (120, 0))
       pg.display.update()

   def draw_nambers():
       z = pg.image.load('1200px-Un1.svg.png')
       z = pg.transform.scale(z, (70,70))
       screen.blit(z, (400,0))
       x = pg.image.load('2.png')
       x = pg.transform.scale(x, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(x, (400, 80))
       c = pg.image.load('3.png')
       c = pg.transform.scale(c, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(c, (400, 150))
       v = pg.image.load('4.png')
       v = pg.transform.scale(v, (50, 60))
       screen.blit(v, (410, 220))
       b = pg.image.load('5.png')
       b = pg.transform.scale(b, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(b, (400, 290))
       n = pg.image.load('6.png')
       n = pg.transform.scale(n, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(n, (400, 360))
       m = pg.image.load('7.png')
       m = pg.transform.scale(m, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(m, (400, 430))
       l = pg.image.load('8.png')
       l = pg.transform.scale(l, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(l, (400, 500))
       k = pg.image.load('9.png')
       k = pg.transform.scale(k, (60, 90))
       screen.blit(k, (409, 570))
       pg.display.update()

   def draw_namberse():
       q = pg.image.load('1200px-Un1.svg.png')
       q = pg.transform.scale(q, (70,70))
       screen.blit(q, (950,0))
       w = pg.image.load('2.png')
       w = pg.transform.scale(w, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(w, (950, 80))
       e = pg.image.load('3.png')
       e = pg.transform.scale(e, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(e, (950, 150))
       r = pg.image.load('4.png')
       r = pg.transform.scale(r, (50, 60))
       screen.blit(r, (960, 220))
       t = pg.image.load('5.png')
       t = pg.transform.scale(t, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(t, (950, 290))
       t = pg.image.load('6.png')
       t = pg.transform.scale(t, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(t, (950, 360))
       y = pg.image.load('7.png')
       y = pg.transform.scale(y, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(y, (950, 430))
       u = pg.image.load('8.png')
       u = pg.transform.scale(u, (70, 70))
       screen.blit(u, (950, 500))
       i = pg.image.load('9.png')
       i = pg.transform.scale(i, (60, 90))
       screen.blit(i, (959, 570))
       pg.display.update()
   ```

Comment: У вас в коде нет никакой обработки событий нажатия кнопок мыши. Как и перемещения чего-бы то ни было. Приведите свой вариант и покажите результат, опишите что именно не получилось

Comment: я не знаю как это сделать, можете пожалуйста помочь?